# Looking for a specific word for anger caused by someone's selfish action

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

I am looking for a word that encompasses the anger felt towards a selfish action, such as suicide. Anyone have something a little direct and powerful?

Comment: That might be ***indignation***

Comment: "rage" usually goes beyond "anger" but is a possibility.

Comment: "outrage" is another good word for condemnation suggested below.  It is not specifically about "self-fish action" .. I think Indignation suggested by @Jim is very good if you want to suggest that you've been insulted by their lack of decorum .

Answer (score 0):

> Condemnation
> kän-ˌdem-ˈnā-shən, kän-ˌdəm-ˈnā-shən/
> noun
>
> 1:  censure, blame.
>
> 2:  the act of judicially condemning.
>
> 3:  the state of being condemned
>
> 4:  a reason for condemning.

Or

> Disapprobation
> dis-a-prə-ˈbā-shən/
> noun
>
> 1:  the act or state of disapproving
>
> 2: refusal to accept as right or desirable.

Comment: Please cite your source(s).

Answer (score 0):

How about [resentment](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/resentment) ? (Definition: the strong and painful bitterness you feel when someone does something wrong to you)